# Getting debug output from WCF 4 REST Template

Tags: wcf, wcf-rest

I'm trying to see the exception that's being thrown in my WCF service but all I get from the response is:

"The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error. For more information about the error, either turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute or from the  configuration behavior) on the server in order to send the exception information back to the client, or turn on tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Framework 3.0 SDK documentation and inspect the server trace logs."

Since I'm doing it the "REST" way, I don't have these options in my web.config.  So, how can I enable "IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults" when using the WCF 4 REST Template?

Comment: Did you have any luck getting this to work ? 

I have the service working but POSTS are failing unless I accept a Stream object instead of a DataContract.

Comment: To get the errors, I just simply caught them in the service and wrote them to a local file.  I could never get them to come back through the web browser and displayed remotely.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I came up with:

Under the standardEndpoint in your web.config, turn on faultExceptionEnabled

```
<standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true" faultExceptionEnabled="true">
```

Then, for custom messages to show, the thrown exceptions must be a FaultException. Here's an example of one that I use:

```
if (!Enum.GetNames(typeof(Models.Games.GsfCurrencyPrice.Sections)).Contains(section)) throw new FaultException<ArgumentException>(new ArgumentException("Value must be one of the following: " + string.Join(", ", Enum.GetNames(typeof(Models.Games.GsfCurrencyPrice.Sections))), "section"));
```

which produces the following response when thrown:

```
<Fault xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/envelope/none"><Code><Value>Sender</Value></Code><Reason><Text xml:lang="en-US">The creator of this fault did not specify a Reason.</Text></Reason><Detail><ArgumentException xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><ClassName i:type="x:string" xmlns="">System.ArgumentException</ClassName><Message i:type="x:string" xmlns="">Value must be one of the following: Buy, Sell</Message><Data i:nil="true" xmlns=""/><InnerException i:nil="true" xmlns=""/><HelpURL i:nil="true" xmlns=""/><StackTraceString i:nil="true" xmlns=""/><RemoteStackTraceString i:nil="true" xmlns=""/><RemoteStackIndex i:type="x:int" xmlns="">0</RemoteStackIndex><ExceptionMethod i:nil="true" xmlns=""/><HResult i:type="x:int" xmlns="">-2147024809</HResult><Source i:nil="true" xmlns=""/><WatsonBuckets i:nil="true" xmlns=""/><ParamName i:type="x:string" xmlns="">section</ParamName></ArgumentException></Detail></Fault>
```

Hope this helps.